# Hyphenation in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to have automatic hyphenation of the text displayed within a TextArea (e.g. SpanLabel) in Codename One?

I've done some research, I don't know the topic and I don't know how different languages are handled. For the moment I have seen that Android has `android:hyphenationFrequency` in TextView xml, and iOS `UITextView` has an `hyphenationFactor`. So I suppose hyphenation might be technically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but we don't support it in our text layout code at this time. It can probably done while editing native code but not in the Java rendering state. You can probably use the `BrowserComponent` to show hyphenated text in a portable way.